# Getting href using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to extract a specific link for this html code

```
<a class="pageNum taLnk" data-offset="10" data-page-number="1" 
href="www.blahblahblah.com/bb32123">Page 1 </a>
<a class="pageNum taLnk" data-offset="20" data-page-number="2" 
href="www.blahblahblah.com/bb45135">Page 2 </a>
```

As you can see, the link (href) are disorganized, therefore there are no pattern for me to use which means I need to extract the href manually using BeautifulSoup.

I want to specifically get Page 2's href.

These can the code I have now.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib

 url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g293917-d539542-r447460956-Duangtawan_Hotel_Chiang_Mai-Chiang_Mai.html#REVIEWS'
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
 for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs = {'class' : 'pageNum taLnk'}):
     print (link)
```

As you can see, I am stuck at trying to obtain the href information specifically for Page 2. Is there anyway to access with extra bit of information within the tags such as `data-page-number = "2"` or `data-offset = "20"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page_2 = soup.find('a', attrs = {'data-page-number' : '2'})
```

This will only get you the page 2, if you want to get the next page no matter what the current page is, you should find the next page url:

```
next_page = soup.find('a', attrs = {'class' = 'nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk'})
```

> Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that
>   can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:
>
> ```
> data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
> data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
> # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
> ```
>
> You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a
>   dictionary and passing the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs
>   argument:
>
> ```
> data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
> # [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
> ```

Comment: @Niche.P I update the code, and please accept the answer.

Comment: yup, I am waiting for the timer, 2 mins left. Thanks